# What a " , " does in a while loop?

Tags: c, loops, syntax, while-loop

I accidentally typed `while(x,0)` instead of `while(x<0)`. The code of course didn't work as planned nor got compiler errors so i took a damn hour to find the mistake.

Why it didn't get a compiler error? And what does the `,` do in the while loop?

Answer (score 1):

```
while(x,0)
```

comma is treated as binary operator and it will return 0, so your loop condition will go false.

Answer (score 1):

In C, a comma is "a binary operator that evaluates its first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second operand and returns this value (and type)."

Since 0 is false then your code was exiting the loop.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator